# Using multiple Comparator to sort List of Strings multiple times

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have been trying to Group the strings ignoring the cases present in an List and trying to Sort them again with case-sensitivity.

So, if I have the inputs as follows:

```
"Abc","DEF","abc","dEf"
```

then my output should be sorted two times as first level of sort using Comparator should be:

```
"Abc","abc","DEF","dEf"
```

and second level of sort should be:

```
"abc","Abc","dEf","DEF"
```

And my code like as follows which contains only single Comparator. Can we achieve such sorting using multiple comparators or tweaking the single Comparator to achieve such logic?

```
public class ListSortIgnoreCaseComparator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("Abc");
        input.add("DEF");
        input.add("abc");       
        input.add("dEf");
        System.out.println("Input: "+input);

        Collections.sort(input, new GroupIgnoreCase());
        System.out.println("Output: "+input);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @author 
 *
 */
class GroupIgnoreCase implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {      
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }

}
/**
 * 
 * @author 
 *
 */
class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s3, String s4) {
        if(s3.equalsIgnoreCase(s4)){
            return s3.compareTo(s4);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Input: [Abc, DEF, abc, dEf]
Output: [Abc, abc, DEF, dEf]
```

Can we tweak the Comparator such that the output is:

```
Output: [abc, Abc, dEf, DEF]
```

instead of above?

Comment: Have you tried using a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/collationintro.html) instead?

Comment: @assylias a `Collator` is sure powerful but writing your own if there's not the one you want is, uh

Comment: @fge I fon't think you need to write one - cf answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can compare them ignoring the case, and only if they are equal, you should compare them again, this time not ignoring the case:

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {      
    int cmp = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = s1.compareTo(s2);
    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: How it can be? Your `compare()` method still return output `Output: [Abc, abc, DEF, dEf]`. Please double check it.

Comment: @Antony Well, my answer shows how to "break the tie" for Strings that are equal based on case insensitive comparison. In case sensitive lexicographical order, the lower case letters come after the upper case letters. If the lower case letters are required to come before the upper case letters, a reverse order would do the trick - `s2.compareTo(s1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with strength [`TERTIARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#TERTIARY):

```
public class ListSortIgnoreCaseComparator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("Abc");
        input.add("DEF");
        input.add("abc");       
        input.add("dEf");
        System.out.println("Input: "+input);

        Collator c = Collator.getInstance();
        c.setStrength(Collator.TERTIARY);

        Collections.sort(input, c);
        System.out.println("Output: "+input);
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Comparing Strings (The Java™ Tutorials > Internationalization > Working with Text)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/collationintro.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    int comVal = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    if (comVal == 0) {
        return s2.compareTo(s1);
    } else {
        return comVal;
    }
}

Input: [Abc, DEF, abc, dEf]
Output: [abc, Abc, dEf, DEF]
```